How can we prove a weak solution (for Poisson's equation) is Hölder when we only know it a.e.?
It is known that if $u\in H^{1}(B_{1})\cap L^{\infty}(B_{1})$ is a weak solution of $\Delta u = f\in L^{\infty}(B_{1})$ in the unit ball $B_{1}$, then $u\in C^{0,\alpha}(B_{1/2})$ for some $\alpha>0$. This is, for example, Corollary 2.12 in Regularity Theory for Elliptic PDE by Fernández-Real and Ros-Oton. The outline of the proof in this book is as follows:

Prove a version of Harnack's inequality: for any weak solution $u\in H^{1}(B_{1})$ with $u\geq 0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\sup_{B_{1/2}}u \leq C\left(\inf_{B_{1/2}}u + \|f\|_{L^{\infty}(B_{1})}\right).
\end{equation}
Harnack's inequality implies an oscillation decay: for any weak solution $u\in H^{1}(B_{1})$,
\begin{equation}
\sup_{B_{1/2}}u - \inf_{B_{1/2}}u \leq (1-\theta)\left(\sup_{B_{1}}u - \inf_{B_{1}}u\right) + 2\|f\|_{L^{\infty}(B_{1})}.
\end{equation}
The oscillation decay implies that if $u$ is also in $L^{\infty}(B_{1})$, then it satisfies
\begin{equation}
\|u\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(B_{1/2})} \lesssim \|u\|_{L^{\infty}(B_{1})} + \|f\|_{L^{\infty}(B_{1})}.
\end{equation}
The proof proceeds by estimating $|u(x)-u(0)|$ directly for $2^{-k-1} \leq |x| \leq 2^{-k}$ for $k\geq 1$ using the oscillation decay from (2).

Here's what I'm confused by: when we begin the proof, we don't yet know that $u$ has a continuous representative (in the sense of functions equal a.e.), and I don't think the results from steps (1) and (2) necessarily hold if $u$ is not the continuous representative. We can replace (1) and (2) with versions replacing sup and inf with essential sup and inf, but this does not seem strong enough to prove the Hölder estimate of step (3).
One thought I had was that you can pick a distinguished representative from the beginning and work with that. We have that $u + \|f\|_{L^{\infty}(B_{1})}x_{1}^{2}$ is subharmonic (as a distribution), implying it is equal a.e. to a subharmonic function. This is enough for the proof to work if the essential sup and inf of a subharmonic function are equal to its actual sup and inf, but I'm not sure if this is true. (Subharmonic functions are upper semicontinuous, so their essential infima are equal to their actual infima, but there are upper semicontinuous functions whose essential suprema are not equal to their actual suprema.) This also seems disproportionate to the problem at hand.
Any advice would be appreciated.
